# Не работает Telethon на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, telethon

Создаю клиент:

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name2', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
```

все работает. Но как только я пытаюсь отправить сообщение:

```
client.send_message('me', 'Бот запустился')
```

появляется ошибка:

```
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.417481+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most
   recent call last):
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.417500+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "poster.py",
   line 2967, in <module>
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.419396+00:00 app[worker.1]:     main_funk()
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.419396+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "poster.py",
   line 2950, in main_funk
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.421085+00:00 app[worker.1]:     CreateClient()
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.421085+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "poster.py",
   line 2941, in CreateClient
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.422793+00:00 app[worker.1]:    
   client.send_message('me', 'Бот запустился1')
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.422794+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File
   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/sync.py",
   line 39, in syncified
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.422914+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return
   loop.run_until_complete(coro)
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.422915+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File
   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 488,
   in run_until_complete
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423143+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return
   future.result()
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423144+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File
   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/client/messages.py",
   line 743, in send_message
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423443+00:00 app[worker.1]:     result = await
   self(request)
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423443+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File
   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py",
   line 75, in __call__
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423565+00:00 app[worker.1]:    
   self.session.process_entities(result)
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423567+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File
   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py",
   line 282, in process_entities
 - 2020-12-19T12:26:10.423744+00:00 app[worker.1]:     'insert or
   replace into entities values (?,?,?,?,?)', rows)
 - **2020-12-19T12:26:10.423750+00:00 app[worker.1]:
   sqlite3.OperationalError: table entities has 6 columns but 5 values
   were supplied**
```

При это при запуске напрямую с пк все работает отлично!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, версия Telethon на Heroku отличалась от версии установленной локально. Файл сессии был создан на ПК локально и не подходил под версию Telethon на Heroku. Я решил проблему используя StringSession